# Is Gringotts really safe?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, horcrux, deathly-hallows, gringotts

Throughout the books we are told that

> there is no safer place than Gringotts... Except hogwarts.

But is it really safe?

I mean, the trio managed to get to the Lestrange vault by using just the Imperius curse.

Look at how easy it was. Clearly any wizard who knows how to cast Imperius might force a goblin to open any vault.

Has this been clarified or explained by J.K.R or mentioned in any of the books?

Comment: Might want to [see this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/63302/31675) - I think that's the best your going to get..

Comment: "Just" using the Imperius Curse? It is one of the three Unforgivable Curses. Wizards might think that worse than robbing a bank.

Comment: Seems very dupey indeed to me.